# Issue/bug with standard spinner

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-events

since last week i've this problem on the org and i'm still not able to solve it.

Here's the details:
In every standard action like creating or editing an account using the standard buttons  `Edit` and `New`, when i save the brand new/edited record there is no standard spinner showing up.

Lately with deeper investigations i've realized that the standard spinner is actually BEHIND the standard popup.

I've some lightning components working on the org but i can't understand why this should interact with the standard actions of create and edit.

May this be related to some sfdc release?

Does anyone can help with this issue?